# Consulta mysql en php para hacer un login

Tags: php, sql

soy nuevo en la programacion y estoy haciendon un proyecto para aplicar conocimientos que voy aprendiendo.
mi problema es el siguiente:
estoy haciendo una pagina de login, para una especie de ecomerce que todavia no realice, la cuestion es la siguiente al completar los formularios envio una consulta a sql y valido datos, pero este me da un error, el cual no logro entender cual es. les dejo el codigo, supuestamente el error esta en la linea 6 pero no logro divisarlo. gracias de antemano!
[cabe aclarar que si funciona para registrarse pero no para logear]

```
session_start();
include('conexion.php');
$mail= $_POST['correo'];
$clave= $_POST['clave'];
$user = mysqli_query($conect,"SELECT mail,contrasena FROM miembros WHERE mail=$mail AND contrasena='$clave'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($user)==1){
    $_SESSION['cliente'] = $mail;
    header('location: ecomerce.php');
}else{
    header('location: index.php?fc');
}
?>
ESTE ES EL ERROR QUE ME DA:
Warning: Undefined array key "correo" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Vale por dos\login.php on line 4

Warning: Undefined array key "clave" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Vale por dos\login.php on line 5

Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND contrasena='' LIMIT 1' at line 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Vale por dos\login.php:6 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Vale por dos\login.php(6): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'SELECT mail,con...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Vale por dos\login.php on line 6
```

Comment: El valor de `mail` debería entrecomillarse, tal y como la contraseña.

Comment: Ademas de ese problema, nos decis que hay un error, y esperas magicamente que adivinemos cual es?? ;)

Comment: Publica el texto completo del error que recibes, si dices que "es en la línea 6", indica cuál es la línea 6. Si cuentas líneas en el código que muestras, la línea 6 es una línea en blanco.

Comment: @gbianchi Me había olvidado, ahí lo edite!

Comment: @Sal Ya probé eso anteriormente y tampoco es :)

Comment: @JuanCarlos Ahi edite y coloque el codigo de error! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente lo que sucede es que las variables que quieres recibir por $_POST ('correo' y 'clave') no corresponden a los nombres de los campos del formulario de login.

Revisa la propiedad *name* de los campos del formulario, esos serán los nombres de las variables que recibes. Por ejemplo, de un `<input type="text" name="abc123">` recibirás la variable `$_POST['abc123']`

También recuerda entrecomillar la variable $mail en la consulta SQL.

Comment: Lo pude solucionar, en parte a lo que me dijiste y al checkear eso me di cuenta que nunca habia puesto el method, muchas gracias!